# Prove the transition map between two linear isomorphism is $A\mapsto BAB^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $GL(V)$ be set of all invertible map over $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{R}$.

For there are two different isomorphism from $GL(V)\to GL(n,\Bbb{R})$  given by different basis of $V$

So we have a transition map $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}:GL(n,\Bbb{R})\to GL(n,\Bbb{R})$

Prove that this transition map has the form $A\mapsto BAB^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $B$.

Comment: thanks it seems reasonable.As a manifold it's $n^{2}$ dimension however correct?

Comment: I'm probably a little rusty,  as usual, but I would guess it's an open submanifold, so same dimension.   But does that come into play? I mean I'm sure it's a Lie group and everything,  but I'm just trying to follow you.

Comment: I realize it now,I misunderstood it to be a vector space before.So we can't call the map $GL(V)\to GL(n,\Bbb{R})$ **linear** isomorphism. (It seems I did something totoally wrong)

Comment: thanks,I will think about more careful later.

Comment: It's actually a group not a vector space,  if I'm not mistaken.   I've made this mistake before.

Comment: The $GL(V)$ doesn't seem relevant to the question. Basically you are asked to prove that every isomorphism on the multiplicative group $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is in the form of $A\mapsto BAB^{-1}$.

Comment: @user1551 Oh ,thanks maybe I get the point,since matrix $M_1$ and $M_2$ are similar if and if they represent the same linear operator on $V$ (i.e. $M_1,M_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V)$)but with possible different basis.And we can find that on both side  of $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}:GL(n,\Bbb{R})\to GL(n,\Bbb{R})$ are in fact the same operator on $GL(V)$ so they are similar.  I will make it clear later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do as follows we first construct the map $$\mu_{B}:GL(V) \to GL(n,\Bbb{R})\\\tau\mapsto\ [\tau]_B$$
as follows:

if we pick a linear map $\tau\in GL(V)$ it has matrix representation under basis $B$.that is $\mu_B(\tau) = [\tau]_B$.We can check it's the group isomorphism between these two group.this is exactly the coordinate chart map we needed.

If we pick another transformation i.e. pick another basis of $V$ then we have another chart map $\mu_C$ such that $\mu_C(\tau) = [\tau]_C$.

Then our goal is to show that $\mu_B\circ\mu^{-1}_C(A) = BAB^{-1}$ for some $B$.what does this map do? $\mu_B\circ\mu_C^{-1}([\tau]_C) = [\tau]_B$ .And we know the change of basis for linear transformation is $[\tau]_B = M_{C,B}[\tau]_CM_{B,C}$ where $M_{B,C}$ is some change of basis matrix.Which is the desired result.